# Does hashing a random value plus an auto increment number ensure uniqueness?

Tags: php, hash

I'm trying to generate a unique order number for my ecommerce application, this is my code:

```
<?php
 $bytes = random_bytes(3);
 $random_hash = bin2hex($bytes);
 $order_num = $random_hash . "1";
 echo strtoupper(hash('crc32b', $order_num));
```

The order number (in the example is 1), is going to be an auto-increment value retrieved from MySQL. 
Does this ensure me uniqueness?

I wanted a short max 8-10 chars unique final value.
An only numbers solution would be fine too.

Comment: What's wrong with `auto_increment`? That's 100% a unique number.

Comment: It won't be unique because `random_bytes(3)` will generate a repeated value after, on average, about 4096 calls.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, most hash algorithms make no guarantee of when collisions might occur, so you're probably just as likely to get a collision with your proposed code as using the random part on its own.

If the auto-increment part is unique, and the random part is just to avoid guesses, you could just concatenate the two parts together (i.e. everything in your example before the `hash` call). That way if the same random number comes up twice, it will have different numbers on the end.

If that results in something too long, you could do something with `base_convert` or `asc` to convert the number into a shorter representation.

Comment: In this case that is not quite true. On 4 byte inputs the CRC32b "hash" function is a permutation, i.e. there are no collisions.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Huh, I stand corrected. In that case I guess padding the order number to 4 bytes and hashing would be good for 4 billion random-looking but guaranteed unique hashes. They'd be easily iterated if someone knew the algorithm, though, which I'm guessing is what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: What you said would be true of most hash functions. The problem in this case is that `random_bytes(3)` will start to produce repeats after about 4096 calls, so that will result in collisions.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Are you saying that changing my code to random_bytes(4) and leaving the rest as you see it will guarantee unique results?

Comment: @thedude12: No, that is not what I'm saying and that is definitely not true. `random_bytes(4)` will start produce to collisions after around 16384 calls.

Answer (score 0):

The hash function will not provide any uniqueness to the id, it only obfuscates the id a bit.

If you have lets say 100 possible values, you would get 100 possible hashes from them, no more. If an attacker wants to brute-force the hashes, he can pick the 100 possible hashes and try them.

In your case with 3 bytes of randomness, you would not get all possible combinations before you get a duplicate. So the same random number would be generated much earlier than with 3 bytes of possible combinations.

There are two common approaches when it comes to unique ids:

1. You let the database automatically increment the id, this makes sure that the id is unique.
2. You generate a UUID (global id with 16 bytes) which offers such a huge keyspace, that a duplicate is extremely unlikely. In practice one can neglate the possiblilty of duplicates.

The UUID has a lot of advantages and one disadvantage:

- (+) UUID's can work decentralized e.g. in an offline scenario.
- (+) One can generate the id before it is inserted in the database, so one has not to wait before the row is created in the db.
- (+) The ids are not deterministic, so an attacker cannot guess the next id.
- (-) They use more storage space and are a bit slower when searching.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I would like a shorter value, more like 8 characters. We are talking about order ids, so a customer makes a purchase and instead of a classic progressive order n.347, 348, 349 and so on (wrong approach for many reasons), I would like some numbers/characters that are generated without the need of checking the database to be sure that the value is unique. What about truncating uuids?

Comment: @thedude12 - That's exactly the problem, either you have a centralized approach like the database counter, or you need numbers which are big enough, so that collisions of random values are nearly impossible. With every truncated byte we increase the chance of collisions. We work with UUID's all the time and I have never seen that performance dropped noticeable because of them (databases offer large int and can still build an index).

Comment: @thedude12 - If obfuscation is your only concern, then search for "obfuscate id" e.g. [Auto-Incrementing IDs](https://philsturgeon.uk/http/2015/09/03/auto-incrementing-to-destruction/), bijektive algorithms exist.